# I am getting issues if I use @property(atomic,retain)NSString *myString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Atomic vs nonatomic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

**I am getting issues (errors) if I use @property(atomic,retain)NSString *myString** like Expected a property attribute before "atomic".

I studied the difference between atomic and nonatomic from Stack Overflow question *[What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)*.

Where do I use atomic and nonatomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that you cannot use the attribute `atomic`. There is either non-atomic or none (atomic is the default case). So you are looking for `@property(retain) NSString *myString;`.

Comment: And also for the most part you want to use "copy" and not "retain" @property (copy) NSString *myString;